# Reduce lots of sloppy paths from a trace to just a few lines?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I keep seeing lots of examples of how to do a traces online with simple images, but when trying a real photo, how do I reduce all the extraneous paths?

[image]

I feel like the resulting trace is very close, but really just want like, one line that goes around the outside of the image.  How do I reduce all the extra paths and say just take the path around the outside of the drawing? I've been trying for hours now, have gone through numerous things that don't seem to work quickly.

Comment: Seems to me that the answer you have gotten is incorrect to what your actually asking in the body of the text. The oustside is pretty easy to do with shapebuilder abd small gap detection.

Comment: @joojaa I traced the attached image and tried the Shape Builder with gap detection, You had and still have a possibility to see a piece of the result in my answer. Harmfully it was only a possibility. The story including Shape Builder was written about 16 hours before your comment.

Comment: @user287001 You dont actually present the gap detection. Anyway, too bad OP didnt include the original picture you could have done better.Anyway the gap detection if tuned well can get rid of some of the kinks.

Comment: So it is well possible that the original photo looks the same as the attached image and the questioner had got quite perfect tracing result but he wants something simpler rhan the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting a photo to line drawing automatically needs very likely something much more clever than tracing with common tracing tools in a vector drawing program. That's because the lines are human abstractions, they very rarely actually exist in photos. Their places can be based on some rules, but finally that's only guessing which maybe is expected.

Ordinary tracing programs do not have any clever rules which understand human recognition. Tracing sees brightness differences locally, it doesn't try to form any overview. It has parameters to fade the separation between too close details. I mean Blur, angle tolerance and area size. And the number of different colors if you are not tracing as black and white. In addition you can try to trace as strokes if there really exists visible curves.

Unfortunately we do not know your image nor know have you already found the best settings. Show the photo and the settings if you expect to get any help which fits into your case.

Generally the only waterproof method is to draw manually those lines which you see to present the photo as you expect. I guess it's not difficult if there really is only few lines you want. Only keep the photo locked below your drawing to prevent it moving in the middle of the job.

You can try to clean the tracing result (after expanding it). You can try to delete manually unwanted paths or split and delete unwanted parts of paths and keep the wanted ones. You only know which are unwanted and do the wanted paths exist in the tracing result.  I guess the needed amount of work is too much and for that reason you are here now.

If the outline around the current jumble really is the curve you want you can try to fill the area with the Shape Builder and combine everything to a single shape with Pathfinder Panel's Unite. Then remove the fill and insert a stroke with good width.

You may need to delete manually most of the anchor points of the curve to get rid of too many twists. Like this:

[image]

To keep Illustrator's job reasonable paint in Photoshop as much black to your Photo inside the wanted area as you can and as much white outside the wanted area as you can.

**I guess the most simple way** is to take Illustrator's Pen, draw the outline and utterly forget messing with garbage.

There exists other software which are designed to trace certain type of photos such as maps or scanned drawings. Freeware Inkscape has also tracing which work differently than Illustrator's Live Trace.  Without knowing what's your photo and what are the wanted lines the actual prediction are they worth trying is impossible